# Type mismatch when importing JSON into Neo4J with Py2Neo

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have a JSON file, the head of which looks like this:

```
"exports": {
        "type": "WordsAndPhrases",
        "date": "2018-08-02T10:07:58.047669Z",
        "relevantYears": "2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017",
        "Words": {
            "H1": "WORDS AND PHRASES:",
            "Word": [
                {
                    "Phrase": {
                        "id": "phrase_2011001932",
                        "title": "A common"
                    },
                    "Document": "Law of Property Act 1925, s 193(1) (as amended)",
                    "Refs": {
                        "CaseTitle": {
                            "id": "2011201246",
                            "title": "ADM Milling Ltd v Tewkesbury Town Council"
                        },
                        "title": "None",
                        "citations": "Lewison J [2011] EWHC 595 (Ch); [2012] Ch 99; [2011] 3 WLR 674, Ch D"
                    }
                },
```

I am using the following script to import the JSON data into Neo4J:

```
import json
from py2neo import Graph, authenticate

authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "foobar")
graph = Graph()

with open('wp.json') as data_file:
    json = json.load(data_file)

query = """
WITH {json} AS document

UNWIND document.exports.Words.Word AS Word

MERGE (Phrase:a {phrase: Word.Phrase.title})
MERGE (Document:b {document: Word.Document})
FOREACH (case in Word.Refs.CaseTitle.title | MERGE (Report:z {report: case}))
"""

# Send Cypher query.
print (graph.run(query, json = json).dump())
```

The first two `MERGE` queries work fine. However, the `FOREACH` query is proving to be problematic. I'm using the `FOREACH` query to deal with instances where there are multiple `CaseTitle` properties in a single block, for example:

```
{
                    "Phrase": {
                        "id": "phrase_2011002042",
                        "title": "Acts contrary to purposes and principles of United Nations"
                    },
                    "Document": "Council Directive 2004/83/EC, art 12(2)(c)",
                    "Refs": [
                        {
                            "CaseTitle": {
                                "id": "2011201814",
                                "title": "Federal Republic of Germany v B"
                            },
                            "title": "None",
                            "citations": "(Joined Cases C-57/09 and C-101/09); [2012] 1 WLR 1076, ECJ"
                        },
                        {
                            "CaseTitle": {
                                "id": "2016008987",
                                "title": "Commissaire général aux réfugiés et aux apatrides v Lounani"
                            },
                            "title": "None",
                            "citations": "EU:C:2017:71; [2017] 4 WLR 52, ECJ"
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

When I run the script, the following error occurs:

```
py2neo.database.status.CypherTypeError: Type mismatch: expected a map but was List{Map{title -> String("None"), CaseTitle -> Map{title -> String("Federal Republic of Germany v B"), id -> String("2011201814")}, citations -> String("(Joined Cases C-57/09 and C-101/09); [2012] 1 WLR 1076, ECJ")}, Map{title -> String("None"), CaseTitle -> Map{title -> String("Commissaire général aux réfugiés et aux apatrides v Lounani"), id -> String("2016008987")}, citations -> String("EU:C:2017:71; [2017] 4 WLR 52, ECJ")}}
```

The JSON appears to be valid. Can anyone recommend a way of dealing with this error?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Word.Refs.CaseTitle.title` you should use `Word.Refs[0].CaseTitle.title`.  In your JSON it is clear that refs is an array, and you're treating it like an object.  The error message is saying this -- when it tries to dereference "CaseTitle" under "Refs", it is expecting a map, but what you gave it was a list of maps.

Comment: Thanks for this, @FrobberOfBits. I've modified the `FOREACH` query to read:


`FOREACH (case in Word.Refs[0].CaseTitle.title | MERGE (Report:z {report: case}))`


I'm now seeing a different error, namely:


`py2neo.database.status.CypherTypeError: Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue`

I'm scratching my head because I would've expect the values in the target property to be recognised as strings?

Comment: What's the rest of that error message? This seems like a similar problem -- you need to update the original question to give the updated error and data sample.  But the error is rather clear -- cypher thinks that your data contains a long number that you're trying to treat like a string, but it's not a string.  To solve this, you have to figure out which number it's seeing in the real data